# Fadein callback not working

Tags: jquery, fadein

I'm just having some minor callback issues with my fadeIn and slideDown.
The callback isn't working properly for the fadeIn and then slideDown.

Instead of post a lot of code here, I'll just post the jQuery code and a link to jsFiddle.

```
$(".send_email_button").click(function(){
    $(".fullscreen").fadeIn(function() {
        $(".send_email").slideDown();
    });
});

$(".email_close").click(function(){
    $(".send_email").slideUp(function() {
        $(".fullscreen").fadeOut();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7zq716bf/

Comment: it works fine. what does not work?

Comment: What I just explained, the fadeIn should work first then the div slides down instead both are showing as soon as I trigger the click. @LuísSoares

Comment: That is not what I'm seeing. I'm seeing the fiddle work as expected. Have you tried setting animation speed to something slower?

Comment: this is the regular behaviour. what did you expect?

Comment: First time you trigger the click, the callback is not working after you click the X button and trigger the click again then the animation seems to be working fine. @rossipedia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it wasn't working as expected the first time, was because the `.send_email` wasn't initially hidden. Set `display: none` on it initially, and then the `.slideDown()` method will be called when the first `.fadeIn()` method ends.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/5u8jdbdr/)

```
.send_email {
    display: none;
}
```

Prior to this, the duration of the initial `.slideDown()` event was `0` because the `.send_email` element was *already* visible.

Answer (score 1):

Ahhhhh ok. I see what's happening.

The default style of your `.send_email` div is visible. So the `slideDown` call is effectively useless, *for the first time it's called*.

Add `style="display:none;"` to the `.send_email` div (or add `.send_email { display: none; }` to your css) and you should see the behavior you want.

```js
    $(".send_email_button").click(function() {
      $(".fullscreen").fadeIn('slow', function() {
        $(".send_email").slideDown('slow');
      });
    });

    $(".email_close").click(function() {
      $(".send_email").slideUp('slow', function() {
        $(".fullscreen").fadeOut('slow');
      });
    });
```

```css
 .edit_users {
   background-color: #ffffff;
   width: 330px;
   height: auto;
   padding: 10px;
   border: 1px solid #ECECEC;
 }
 .send_email {
   margin: 85px 0 0 50px;
 }
 .email_close {
   background-image: url("http://i.epvpimg.com/5oVbc.png");
   background-repeat: repeat;
   width: 15px;
   height: 17px;
   font-size: 11pt;
   font-weight: 600;
   cursor: pointer;
   opacity: 0.3;
 }
 #content .email_close:hover {
   opacity: 0.6;
 }
 .fullscreen {
   background-image: url("http://i.epvpimg.com/VLXQe.png");
   background-repeat: repeat;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   padding: 0;
   margin: -30px;
   position: fixed;
   z-index: 2;
   display: none;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="button" class="send_email_button" value="Send email" />
<div class="fullscreen">
  <div class="send_email edit_users" style="display:none;">
    <form method="post" action="">
      <div class="email_close right"></div>
      <h2>Send email to User</h2>
      <input type="text" name="email_subject" required placeholder="Subject" autocomplete="off" style="width: 300px;" />
      <input type="email" name="email_address" id="email" disabled placeholder="<?php echo $result['user_email']; ?>" autocomplete="off" style="width: 300px;" />
      <textarea name="email_message" required rows="7" cols="40" style="width: 300px;"></textarea>
      <center>
        <input type="submit" name="email_submit" value="Send" />
      </center>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```